# Writing contents of variable into a file with CF's WriteDump?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

Does the following save my file to the current folder or save to a file at all? Because I can't find the file anywhere:

```
something = doSomething();
WriteDump(var=something, format='html', output="results.html");
```

I'm on MacOS X running CF9.

Answer (score 5):

Quoting the [docs for `cfdump`](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-d-e/cfdump.html) (which is the tag variant of `writeDump`):

> The filename must include the full pathname of the file. You can specify an absolute path, or a path that is relative to the ColdFusion temporary directory. You can use the GetTempDirectory() function to determine the ColdFusion temporary directory.

Your dump is stored in the (system's) temp directory. If you want to store it in the directory of the script, use:

```
something = doSomething();
dumpLocation = expandPath("results.html");
WriteDump(var=something, format='html', output=dumpLocation);
```